# Sort +4 command throwing an error in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu

When I try to run the following command it throws an error.

```
ls -lr | egrep "txt$|tab$" | sort -rn+4
```

The error message:

```
sort: invalid option -- '+'
Try `sort --help' for more information.
```

How can I run this command? Can you explain what is the functionality of sort +4?

Comment: what you trying to do? if you like to know more sort functionality just see it manual it very clear .The above command is look like to display the contents of file in reverse order of 4.And also + is not required in sort command as `sort -rn4` ,r for reverse and n for numerical, 4 number  to be sort

Comment: Why do you output the directory listing in reverse order, just to sort it again afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

The `+POS.COL`  syntax was deprecated in 2002.

To get the old behaviour set an environment variable: `_POSIX2_VERSION=199209`, actually any value not empty, and less then 200112 will do.

See also [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Standards-conformance.html).

Answer (score 1):

`sort` does not accept `+4`, according to its manpage. If you want to sort by the 4th column, use `-k4`.

Btw, I would not use `ls|grep` for a script, better use the `find` command in combination with `xargs`:

```
find -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.tab' | xargs ls -lh | sort -rnk4
```

To make `find` only consider the current directory, specify the `maxdepth` option:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.tab'
```

Comment: what is the issue if we use grep..??

Comment: Well, several reasons: output of `ls` may change in future versions (although this is unlikely), output of `ls` may differ due to different configurations or OS, `ls` outputs everything, `find` only those filenames you are interested in.